# code change alert/email

Tags: files, emails, security

Is there a module to help me receive email for any change in drupal site ?

https://www.drupal.org/project/logging_alerts this module help a lot in log in / log out and add content .. but I need to know about any change even without login to Drupal CMS ..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it sounds like you should install the [Paranoia](https://www.drupal.org/project/paranoia) module, as it will reduce the likelyhood of changes happening.

Then, since you already have logging_alerts, you could program a [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to md5 hash all your files, and send to [watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7) a high-severity message when one changes.  This would then get kicked forward to your email.  Unfortunately, most configuration settings are stored in the database (that is changing in Drupal 8) so just hashing your files will only find code alterations.  Because your question asks "for any change" I will add the [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module to my answer.  Features lets you package up configurations (views, panels, content types, etc) and export them to coded modules.  Then, in that same hook_cron, add a features-revert to force the removal of any changes to the parts that you have exported to a feature.  There is more that can be done, but after this point the effort to accomplish it overshadows the benefit.  If that is not enough, read [Greggles' work](http://crackingdrupal.com/) or watch some of the security sessions from a [drupalcamp](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5fe3MR2yjHAd1t7qrjUa9A)

P.S. Welcome to StackExchange